# How to change Yarn default packages directory?

Tags: laravel, config, yarnpkg

When Yarn is used to install dependencies, it puts them in `node-modules` directory by default.

How can I change this to i.e Laravel `resources` folder?
Like `.bowerrc` is used for bower to set `"directory": "resources/assets"`

Comment: See this link for reference - https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/package-json#toc-directories

Comment: to me this question hasn't been answered. There is packages that you need to install for the server side (e.g. `express`) others that you need from browser side e.g. `jquery`, `bootstrap`, `font-awesome`. I used NPM for server and bower for jquery, bootstrap etc ... now with **Yarn** alone I still don't know how to change destination for a particular library that I want in my `assets/vendor` folder instead or `node_modules`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
yarn install --modules-folder ./resources
```

**UPDATE:**
Keep an eye on this GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1684) as this feature is not quite stable.

**UPDATE 2:** From [Damien's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356340/damien) answer below, you can add `--install.modules-folder "./resources"` to a [`.yarnrc` file](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarnrc/#toc-cli-arguments) so that you don't need to continually pass the commandline argument in for each subsequent invocation. Note that double quotes are required; without those, you will get an `Invalid value type 1:25` or similar error.

You can then commit the `.yarnrc` to source control so that other developers on the project can use the same settings automatically.

Comment: this is a horrible solution.  Things like this need to be global options, not one-off command-line switches.  I am baffled how so many of these node.js solutions seem to have been designed in a non-networked, silo'ed environment.  Many networked systems put the user directory on a network share.  But GLOBAL installs are at a system level, not user level.  There there needs to be a "yarn global install whatever-app" that does not require the user to override the modules folder on the command-line.  Looks like I will be submitting yet another github pull request to have denied. haha

Comment: For the record : You can use `.yarnrc`  file to set this option using `--install.modules-folder resources` ([documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarnrc))

Comment: This will work, but will break `require('some_package')` inside webpack/any js file you have. So the solution is not 100%

Comment: I have had the same issue, and using .yarnrc to define the install modules folder means that ~all~ yarn files are installed in that folder. If using Yarn as a Bower replacement, to install js libraries like bootstrap, jquery etc that need to be installed in a publically accessible directory, then even Yarn files are included (and web-accessible), which i'm not sure is the best thing either. I'm looking for a way to install Yarn-specific files in node_modules (outside of document root) and libraries / dependencies (jquery etc.) in /app/public/assets/vendor

Answer (score 26):

You can create a **.yarnrc** file with the following content:

```
--modules-folder resources
```

This way every `yarn` command will have this parameter set.

Comment: Just wanted to add that even though this got downvoted, it was **correct**. Furthermore, you can add scope: `--install.module-folder` will set this value only for the `install` command, while `--*.modules-folder` should apply for every command (thus _should_ behave the same behaviour as the first command)

Answer (score -1):

When using yarn run you need to do the following:

```
   ln -sf /opt/myproject/node_modules
   yarn config set -- --modules-folder /opt/myproject/node_modules
```

It seems that yarn run doesn't use .yarnrc

Third, it is a good idea to place your source code under a separate directory that you mount as Docker volume or Vagrant shared folder separately from the node_modules or vendor. On Docker the volume is mounted over your current directory (so you shouldn't e.g. mount . -> /app, but src -> /app/src ). The same applies also for vagrant with Oracle virtualbox due to the "sendfile" -kernel call bug that causes the JS and CSS files to be cut randomly in between if node_modules is served from the shared folder.

Fourth, for the reasons of binary incompability the node_modules should be baked inside the virtual machine / image and not on the volume shared folder. Node.js is actually compiled against c++ libraries, which means that if you run npm/yarn install and share node_modules from Mac to Docker (running Linux), you will get Segmentation Fault since OSX binaries are not compatible with Linux binaries. Same goes also for Linux to Linux if you use e.g. Ubuntu on host machine and Alpine Linux on the container, or different Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score -2):

According to [Yarn Docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/package-json#toc-directories), you can specify directories in `package.json` file

```
{
  "directories": {
    "lib": "path/to/lib/",
    "bin": "path/to/bin/",
    "man": "path/to/man/",
    "doc": "path/to/doc/",
    "example": "path/to/example/"
  }
}
```

When installing your package, you can specify exact locations to put binary files, man pages, documentation, examples, etc.

Comment: just tried, but all dependencies are still installed in node_modules. Does this work for you? These are maybe inside the package to sort files if package is supporting it

Comment: it doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300008/how-to-change-dependency-installation-directory-at-yarn